# Migrating HttpSessionListener after adopting spring-sessions

Tags: java, spring-session

We recently started using spring-session in our project. This is a legacy application and we have some [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html). So when the session is expired or user invalidates the session [`sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed(javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent)) method is called. You can get hold of the `HttpSession` that is about to be destroyed by calling [`getSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionEvent.html#getSession()) method on `HttpSessionEvent`

Spring sessions also has something similar. The Redis Session Repository implementation will fire [`org.springframework.session.events.SessionDestroyedEvent`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/spring-session/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/events/SessionDestroyedEvent.java) event and you can add a [ApplicationListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) to it to do some processing.

But this does not fullfill my need.

The problem that i am having is, it cannot be used to migrate our existing HttpSessionListener to use these even because of 2 main reason

1. The event fired by Spring Session only gives the session id that is about to be destroyed. It does not give a copy of the entire session objects. So if my existing HttpSessionListener has some logic to use some attributes for some processing, i cannot do it now.
2. There is no event when the session is created. We have HttpSessionListener which does some work when sessions are created.

So what all options do i have to get our functionality that we had with HttpSessionListener working in spring session?

Answer (score 8):

Spring Session has support for HttpSessionListener from spring session 1.1.

You will have to configure SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter as a bean in the HttpSessionConfig file as follows:

```
@Bean
public SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter session() {
        List<HttpSessionListener> listeners = new ArrayList<HttpSessionListener>();
        listeners.add(new MyListener());
        return new SessionEventHttpSessionListenerAdapter(listeners);
}
```

As you see above, I have registered my custom HttpSessionListener called MyListener. In this you can configure the session created and destroyed events as required.

```
public class MyListener implements HttpSessionListener {

@Override
public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    System.out.println("CREATED--------");
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
    System.out.println("DELETED--------");
}
}
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This works for me, thanks. Answer should be marked as "solution".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't support for HttpSessionListener yet. Please vote in the [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/4)